# setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 when installing scikit-gpuppy

Tags: python, installation, pip, anaconda, cython

I am trying to install the package scikit-gpuppy using `pip` in the anaconda prompt, but I get the following error:

```
(base) C:\Users\PXS>pip install scikit-gpuppy
Collecting scikit-gpuppy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/78/20/3bf5e38217daf2cc5e4458a188ffff2d72db0fd3966886dc2db3145686db/scikit-gpuppy-0.9.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Compiling skgpuppy/UncertaintyPropagation2.pyx because it depends on c:\users\pxs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Includes\numpy\__init__.pxd.
    [1/1] Cythonizing skgpuppy/UncertaintyPropagation2.pyx

    Error compiling Cython file:
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    ...
    #cython: boundscheck=False
    ^
    ------------------------------------------------------------

    skgpuppy\UncertaintyPropagation2.pyx:1:0: 'skgpuppy/UncertaintyPropagation2'
 is not a valid module name
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\PXS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k0a35tlj\scikit-gpuppy\setup.py", line 20, in <module>
        extensions = cythonize(extensions,compiler_directives={'boundscheck': False})
      File "c:\users\pxs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1026, in cythonize
        cythonize_one(*args)
      File "c:\users\pxs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1146, in cythonize_one
        raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
    Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: skgpuppy/UncertaintyPropagation2.pyx

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\PXS\AppD
ata\Local\Temp\pip-install-k0a35tlj\scikit-gpuppy\
```

Regarding my system:

1. Win 64 bit
2. Python 3.6.5 | Anaconda
3. Already updated "setuptools" and "cython"

The error is very confusing, so any suggestions is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I think this is a bug worth reporting. You could probably work around by temporary removing cython from your installation, thus triggering the fallback-installation from the provided c-file instead of the pyx-file.

Comment: I am not sure how to report a bug. I also tried removing Cython -- didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I tried:

1. I downloaded the package "GPUPPY" from the github [here](https://github.com/snphbaum/scikit-gpuppy)
2. Made sure I have Visual C++ 14.0 installed
3. Installed it using `python setup.py install`

Installing the package using `pip` would not work even after installing Visuall C++! I hope someone knows why. Thanks!